# C++ enum value initialization

Tags: c++, enums

I have an enum declared in my code as:

```
enum REMOTE_CONN
{
    REMOTE_CONN_DEFAULT = 0,
    REMOTE_CONN_EX_MAN = 10000,
    REMOTE_CONN_SD_ANNOUNCE,
    REMOTE_CONN_SD_IO,
    REMOTE_CONN_AL,
    REMOTE_CONN_DS
};
```

I expect the value of REMOTE_CONN_SD_IO to be 10002, but when debugging the value of ((int)REMOTE_CONN_SD_IO) was given as 3.

Another component uses the same enum and it gives the expected value of 10002 to REMOTE_CONN_SD_IO.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: That's surprising. What compiler was this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'll guess.

The first component was built before you changed the code in the header. Try rebuilding the offending component.

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer is that your executable wasn't rebuilt properly after you set REMOTE_CONN_EN_MA = 10000 so what your debugging doesn't match what you're looking at.